# In dalvik, what expression will generate instructions 'not-int' and 'const-string/jumbo'?

Tags: java, android, dalvik, instructions

I am new on learning dalvik, and I want to dump out every instruction in dalvik.
But there are still  3 instructions I can not get no matter how I write the code.
They are 'not-int', 'not-long', 'const-string/jumbo'.

I written like this to get 'not-int' but failed:

```
int y = ~x;
```

Dalvik generated an 'xor x, -1' instead.

and I know 'const-string/jumbo' means that there is more than 65535 strings in the code and the index is 32bit. But when I decleared 70000 strings in the code, the compiler said the code was too long.

So the question is: how to get 'not-int' and 'const-string/jumbo' in dalvik by java code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const-string/jumbo` is easy.  As you noted, you just need to define more than 65535 strings, and reference one of the later ones.  They don't all need to be in a single class file, just in the same DEX file.

Take a look at [dalvik/tests/056-const-string-jumbo](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/kitkat-release/tests/056-const-string-jumbo/), in particular the "build" script that generates a Java source file with a large number of strings.

As far as `not-int` and `not-long` go, I don't think they're ever generated.  I ran `dexdump -d` across a pile of Android 4.4 APKs and didn't find a single instance of either.